# Facebook iOS SDK: presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession crashes

Tags: crash, modal-dialog, feed, facebook-ios-sdk

Using Facebook iOS SDK 3.7, Xcode 4.6, iOS simulator 6.0.

Here is my code:

```
NSLog (@"opening session");
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions: @[@"publish_actions"]
                                   defaultAudience: FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      allowLoginUI: YES
                                 completionHandler: nil];
NSLog (@"open active session completed");
if ([FBSession activeSession].isOpen)
{
    NSLog (@"initiating feed dialog");
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession: nil
                                           parameters: nil
                                              handler: nil];
}
```

When executed, it crashes with the following output to the debug console:

```
opening session
open active session completed
initiating feed dialog
-[FBDialog initWithURL:params:isViewInvisible:frictionlessSettings:delegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb93c7e0
```

I tried several variations, they all crash; the variation above is the simplest.

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that legacy code elsewhere in the system (an old version of the ShareKit library) was colliding with the Facebook SDK.  When I removed the legacy code, then the code in the question above worked properly.